# Any difference between "send_user" and "puts" in Expect?

Tags: tcl, expect

It's not clear to me if `send_user` is the same as `puts`. Every time I want to send an informative message to the user, I would wonder which one I should use. From Expect's man page, it seems like `send_user` is the same as `puts` but then what is `send_user` used for?

Comment: They _might_ be the same; Expect predates a lot of Tcl's own IO handling…

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Another difference I just discovered between the two, apart from the newline thing, is that if you're using `log_file` in your Expect script, statements sent via `send_user` will make it into the logfile, whereas statements sent with `puts` do not.  If you're automating some Expect scripts which aren't being run on your actual console, that can make a big difference.

Answer (score 14):

The main difference is that `puts` automatically appends a newline and 
`send_user` does not. In this regard, `puts -nonewline` is more analagous 
to `send_user`.

`send_user` also "inherits" some options from expect's `send`, such as `-s`
and `-h` (check the expect man page for details). See
http://99-bottles-of-beer.net/language-expect-249.html
for a usage of the `-h` flag.

I cannot speak to how they're implemented at the C-level.